# Images not showing in listview

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am new to Android and am having problems getting examples to do what they do in the book I referencing.

The main gist of the problem is I am building an application that is supposed to show images and some text in a ListView. The text shows up but not the images.  I originally just put the filename in quotes in ListItem classes Source property.

I am trying to reference the drawable directory of Resources but am not having any success accessing it.

Here is the code

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Text;

    using Android.App;
    using Android.Content.PM;
    using Android.OS;
    using Android.Runtime;
    using Android.Views;
    using Android.Widget;

    using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace ListViewExample
    {
         public class ListItem
        {
            public string Source { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public string Price { get; set; }
        }

        public class ListViewCustom : ContentPage
        {
            public ListViewCustom()
            {
                ListView listView = new ListView();
                listView.ItemsSource = new ListItem[]
                {new ListItem{Source=Resource.first.png,Title="First",Description="1st item", Price="$100.00" },
                 new ListItem{Source=Resource.second.png,Title="Second",Description="2nd item", Price="$200.00" },
                new ListItem{Source=Resource.third.png,Title="Third",Description="3rd item", Price="$300.00" }
               };

                listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ImageCell));
                listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding        (ImageCell.ImageSourceProperty, "Source");
                listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(ImageCell.TextProperty, "Title");
                listView.ItemTemplate.SetBinding(ImageCell.DetailProperty, "Description");
                listView.RowHeight = 80;
                listView.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
                listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListItemCell));
                Content = listView;

                listView.ItemTapped += async (sender, e) =>
                {
                    ListItem item = (ListItem)e.Item;
                    await DisplayAlert("Tapped", item.Title.ToString(), " was selected.", "OK");
                    ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
                };
            }
        }

        public class ListItemCell : ViewCell
        {
            public ListItemCell()
            {
                Image image = new Image()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
                };

                StackLayout imageLayout = new StackLayout()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    Children =
                    {image}
                };

                Label titleLabel = new Label()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    FontSize = 25,
                    WidthRequest = 100,
                    FontAttributes = Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes.Bold,
                    TextColor = Color.White
                };
                titleLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Title");

                Label descLabel = new Label()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    FontSize = 12,
                    WidthRequest = 100,
                    TextColor = Color.White
                };
                descLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Description");

                StackLayout viewLayoutItem = new StackLayout()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                    Padding = new Thickness(10, 0, 50, 10),
                    Children =
                    {
                        imageLayout,
                        titleLabel,
                        descLabel
                    }
                };

                Label priceLabel = new Label()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                    FontSize = 25,
                    FontAttributes = Xamarin.Forms.FontAttributes.Bold,
                    TextColor = Color.Aqua
                };
                priceLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Price");

                StackLayout viewLayout = new StackLayout()
                {
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                    Padding = new Thickness(25, 10, 55, 15),
                    Children =
                    {
                        viewLayoutItem,
                        priceLabel
                    }
                };

                View = viewLayout;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.  It's probably something stupid, but like I said I am new to Android

*Edit (adding this as an edit for the OP who posted it as a answer after comments under hvaughan3's answer):

Well, I can't show the code here as it is too long for a comment. Basically the error is either of these to statements in MainActivity.cs

```
global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
LoadApplication (newListViewExample.App ())
```

I haven't done anything to the file, so I am a bit confused as why I am getting the error. I even tried recreating the project. Same results.

PS: In answer to hvaughan3, the images are located in the Resources\drawable directory. And yes I did change the listview.itemssource statement to just have double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for your help Vaughn

Answer (score 0):

#### Have you tried adding Source binding?

```
Image image = new Image()
{
  HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand
};
//add this missing binding
image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty,"Source");
```

Comment: That's what I have

Comment: listView.RowHeight = 80;
            listView.BackgroundColor = Color.Black;
        **listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListItemCell**
            Content = listView;

Comment: I have already removed the code involving ImageCell per hvaughan3's suggestion

Comment: have you tried adding the missing binding? I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few issues that I can see here. Based on the issues you are having, I would first highly recommend that you work through (not just read) the [Xamarin Form's Binding Docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/).

In the code you posted, you are setting the `ListView.ItemTemplate` 5 times, that property can only be set or bound a single time. You assign something to it 2 times (`listView.ItemTemplate = ...`) and you try binding something to it 3 times (`listView.SetBinding()`). Each time, it is overwriting the previous one.

So my first suggestion is to just stick with the very last assignment:

```
listView.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ListItemCell));
```

The next issue is that you are not binding anything to your `ListItemCell`'s `Image`. You would want to do something like:

```
image.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, "Source");
```

Finally, when you declare your `ListView.ItemSource` you are setting each `ListItem.Source` but you are not enclosing the `Resource.first.png` in double quotes. Also, are the images named `Resource.first.png` or are they actually named `first.png`? If they are actually named `first.png` then you should set `ListItem.Source` to `first.png` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the input. However, after making the changes you suggested, the images still don't show up.  Most of what you suggested was my attempt to fix the problem, like I said I'm new, so I was trying any suggestion I could find.

Comment: @user182162 Definitely understand the feeling! I do the same thing. So you are only setting `ItemTemplate` once, you are setting the `Image`'s binding, and did you end up using `first.png` or `Resource.first.png`? Also I had a problem with the `Image` binding. Please see my edited code. Also, where are the images located? Are they in the native iOS and Android projects? If so, are what directories are they in for each project? What is their build action set to (highlight the image in VS and open the properties panel)?

Comment: Well, I think I found the problem. I wasn't binding the ListItem source to the image.  However, I am unable to test the fix as I am getting a runtime error on the following code.  (See next comment)

Comment: Well, I can't show the code here as it is too long for a comment.  Basically the error is either of these to statements in MainActivity.cs                                                  'global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
LoadApplication (new ListViewExample.App ());'

Comment: @user182162 What is the error or exception? The usually means that the exception is happening when it first tries to load `ListViewExample.App ()`.

Comment: It is an invalid cast exception